# In a Sun Disk Label scheme, what are partitions of type E and F?

Tags: mount, solaris

I am working with an image (dd) of an HDD removed from a Sun server that was in use circa 2006.

Using `fdisk` on a Debian system to view the partition table it shows 3 partitions:

```
Partition 2: A type 5, whole disk - as is the norm.

Partition 3: At cylinder 0, 1 cylinder long, type f.

Partition 4: At cylinder 1, the rest of the disk, type e.
```

I can't find any documentation to tell me what partitions of type E or F might be.

I've used `disktype` and `file` to examine the disk and volumes respectively, but with no luck.

There is a partner disk in the server which has root and var partitions of type `UFS`. From what I've seen on this disk, the original disk might be part of a `vxfs` disk group, but I don't know how to find out or mount the partition.

Can anybody suggest any next steps?

**Edit:** The partition table as shown by `format` on SunOS...

```
Part      Tag    Flag     Cylinders        Size            Blocks
  0 unassigned    wm       0               0         (0/0/0)           0
  1 unassigned    wm       0               0         (0/0/0)           0
  2     backup    wu       0 - 4923        8.43GB    (4924/0/0) 17682084
  3          -    wu       0 -    0        1.75MB    (1/0/0)        3591
  4          -    wu       1 - 4923        8.43GB    (4923/0/0) 17678493
  5 unassigned    wm       0               0         (0/0/0)           0
  6 unassigned    wm       0               0         (0/0/0)           0
  7 unassigned    wm       0               0         (0/0/0)           0
```

And the output from `fdisk` on Debian:

```
Disk file.dd (Sun disk label): 27 heads, 133 sectors, 4924 cylinders
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 bytes

Device   Flag    Start       End    Blocks   Id  System
file.dd3  u          0  17682084   8841042    5  Whole disk
file.dd4  u          0      3591      1795+   f  Unknown
file.dd5  u       3591  17682084   8839246+   e  Unknown
```

**Edit:** bit more info...

In `fdisk` (on Debian) the Sun disklabel partition types are listed as:

```
 0  Unassigned       4  SunOS usr        8  SunOS home      82  Linux swap     
 1  Boot             5  Whole disk       9  SunOS alt secto 83  Linux native   
 2  SunOS root       6  SunOS stand      a  SunOS cachefs   8e  Linux LVM      
 3  SunOS swap       7  SunOS var        b  SunOS reserved  fd  Linux RAID auto
```

'e' and 'f' simply aren't listed.

Comment: EF, maybe? For EFI? [Oracle seems](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1459/disksconcepts-1.html) to be fond of the term, and `fdisk` has a [type *ef*](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html).

Comment: Thanks @minix for the edits. I wrote the question on the Android app. Haven't spotted how to format properly on it yet.

Comment: Thanks @mikeserv, but I think the EF type is for the MS-DOS style partition types, rather than the Sun disklabel that I'm working with.

Comment: From a SPARC or x86 box?  FWIW, neither 'e' nor 'f' are in Solaris `sys/vtoc.h`:  http://cr.illumos.org/~webrev/gdamore/noknr/usr/src/uts/common/sys/vtoc.h-.html

Comment: Thanks all. I'm at home so no access to the original Sun disklabels atm. Will post the originals when I get a chance to see if it sheds some light. @mikeserv, [fdisk understands DOS-type partition tables and BSD- or SUN-type disklabels](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk), so we're talking about the Sun/BSD type, not the DOS-type - hence the different type IDs.

Comment: Thank you! Did I link to a DOS `fdisk` doc? Sorry man - it was such a big list i just scanned all of the way to the bottom cause google told me it was there. For what it's worth I definitely didn't see any e,f types in the Oracle docs - which is why i went looking for `fdisk` - though i could swear i read something about not using anything but their fdisk. i'll look once more - but im sorry i couldn't be more help.